# How secure are mobile phone communications?

Tags: mobile

It's very common to hear about encryption in web browsers and apps, but that's all about the internet. But what about mobile communications that use a SIM card, like ordinary text messages and voice calls, that does not require internet access. How are they encrypted ? I've heard of protocols like **3GPP**, and many others, but I dont think they are mandatory!
Every help and guidance will be appreciated!!!

Comment: Seel also this question: [Best way to keep cell day to day phone calls private - is VOIP better?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/118812/best-way-to-keep-cell-day-to-day-phone-calls-private-is-voip-better).

Comment: That's a very broad question and depends on which technology you are referring to. You may want to read up on A5/1 which is no longer considered secure, A5/2 which I think was never meant to be highly secure, both of which are for pre-3G telecom. In terms of currently used ciphers, look up SNOW 3G.

Comment: @automatictester Thankyou for the reply! But why are they not using AES or ECDH ?

Comment: They aren't secure. And they aren't using secure ciphers because they don't care. Its a surveillance network at this point, why would they try to secure it?